# JavaFX How to switch from different windows

Tags: model-view-controller, authentication, interface, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making a JAVAFX application in which I first want users to log in (in the very first prompted window) and, depending on the success or not, I want to create a different huge window which will be the global interface of the app.

I try to do it following the MVC pattern, though in JavaFX it does not seem to be a very clear separation. I have the views (two xml files), one controller (for both the views and the model) and the model.

Since the very first scene is always created in the main class, how can I hide that one and create a new one (corresponding to the global interface) when the user presses the login button??

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch between panes in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176701/switch-between-panes-in-javafx)

Comment: Also similar to: [Switching between windows in JavaFX 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915544/switching-between-windows-in-javafx-2-2)