# Loading new fxml in the same scene

Tags: javafx, fxml, scene

I have 2 fxml files:

- Layout (header, menubars and content)
- Anchorpane (it's supposed to be placed inside the content from the other fxml file)

I would like to know how can I load the second file inside the content space from the "Master" scene. And is that a good thing to do working in javaFX or is it better to load a new scene?

I'm trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane content;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {        
    content = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load("vista2.fxml");
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the loader creates a new AnchorPane, but you never add the new pane to a parent in the scene graph.

Comment: can you tell me how can I add the new pane to a parent in the scene, please? I'm new using JavaFX

Comment: I created an answer to supply some more detail on fxml loading.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**Why your code does not work**

The loader creates a new AnchorPane, but you never add the new pane to a parent in the scene graph.

**Quick Fix**

Instead of:

```
content = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load("vista2.fxml");
```

Write:

```
content.getChildren().setAll(FXMLLoader.load("vista2.fxml"));
```

Replacing the content children with your new vista.  The content itself remains in the scene graph, so when you set it's children, you are also attaching them to the scene graph at the same time.

You might need to play around with layout (e.g. work with auto resizing layouts like StackPanes rather than AnchorPanes) to get the exact behaviour you want.

Rather than just adopting the quick fix, I would advise reviewing the simple framework linked below as that might provide you with a more general purpose mechanism to get the behaviour you want.

**Reference FXML Navigation Framework**

I created a [small framework](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6460130) for swapping fxml controlled content panes in and out of a portion of the main scene.

The mechanism of the framework is the same as suggested in kithril's answer.

1. A main pane for the outer fxml acts as a holder for child panes.
2. The main controller for the outer fxml supplies a public method that can be used to swap the child panes.
3. A convenience navigator class is statically initialized with the main controller for the outer layout.
4. The navigator provides a public static method to load a new child pane into the main container (by invoking a method on the main controller).
5. Child panes are generated in the navigator by their respective fxml loaders.

**Why a Framework**

The framework seems like overkill for answering your question, and perhaps it is.  However, I have found that the two most asked topic related to FXML are:

1. Navigation between panes generated by FXML (this question).
2. [How to pass data between FXML controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml).

So I felt that a small demo framework was warranted for this case.

**Sample Framework Output**

The first screen shows the application layout displaying the first vista.  The contents are a header which is defined in the main application layout and an aliceblue colored interchangable child content pane.

[image: vista1]

In the next screen, the user has navigated to the second vista, which retains the constant header from the main layout and replaces the original child pane with a new coral colored child content pane.  The new child has been loaded from a new fxml file.

[image: vista2]

**Looking for Something More Substantial?**

A lightweight framework which is more extensive and better supported than the sample framework from this question is [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com).

**Looking for Something Even Simpler?**

Just swap out the scene root: [Changing Scenes in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463793/1155209).

**Other Options?**

Animated Transitions and others: [Switch between panes in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176701/switch-between-panes-in-javafx)

Comment: @jewelsea - Thank you very much for this mini-framework for loading new fxml to the same scene. I have implemented this in my small app, but how to bring in the Model, view and controllers interaction in this framework? any pointers or code samples that you have? Thank yo very much.

Comment: Your Answer looks good but I'm not able to solve this problem. Is there ant tutorial for this problem for beginner ?

Comment: @jewelsea, afterburner.fx is archived and it is pointing to online shopping portal. can you delete your comment to avoid spam flags :)

Comment: @Raju Thanks for your comment, I deleted the comment and placed a link to afterburner.fx (current relocated real site not a shopping portal) in the answer.

Comment: @jewelsea A bit off-topic but what is considered better practice, Loading new fxml in the same scene or switching different scenes?

Comment: @someFolk If you are changing the root of the scene, then I don't think it matters much if you change the entire scene or just the root.  If you are changing parts of the scene and not the whole thing, then loading new fxml just for the changing part rather than recreating the entire scene makes sense.

Comment: I know this is late!! but I am getting a error saying no suitable method found when used FXMLloader

Comment: I'm using your framework but I have a problem. I'm trying to swap fxml in a already swapped fxml. I mean, I have a main pane with a toolbar, and depending on which button of the toolbar you click, then you show a different pane on the content on the scene. But then what I want to do is that if the user clicks in a button inside this new pane, then the children panes changes too. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jewelsea done -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327157/loading-multiple-fxml-in-javafx

Comment: Thank you very much for this framework but I can't pass parameter from one controller to another, I have searched and I didn't find it. I tried to set id to controller2 while using controller1 and then I tried to get id from controller2 but I couldn't.

Comment: @SeyitBilal there are various methods for [passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310). If you are having an issue with it, you should create a new question that includes a [mcve].

Comment: Should I load FXML every time the view is to be shown or rather keep it all "cached"?

Answer (score 7):

Im not sure about how effective this is, but seems to be just fine and what's more, much simpler to methods above.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDVztNtJWOo

As far as I understood what is happening here is this(its really similiar to what is happening in Start() method in application class) :

```
private void buttonGoToWindow3Action(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    Parent window3; //we need to load the layout that we want to swap
    window3 = (StackPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ScenePackage/FXMLWindow3"));

    Scene newScene; //then we create a new scene with our new layout
    newScene = new Scene(window3);

    Stage mainWindow; //Here is the magic. We get the reference to main Stage.
    mainWindow = (Stage)  ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    mainWindow.setScene(newScene); //here we simply set the new scene
}
```

However Im not a java expert and quite new to programing so it would be good if someone experienced would evaluate it.

EDIT:
Ive found even simpler method;

Go to MainApplication class and make static Stage parentWindow.

```
public static Stage parentWindow;
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    parentWindow = stage;

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ScenePackage/FXMLMainScene.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Now you get acces to your main Stage so anywhere in a program you can do something like that to change the scene:

```
    Parent window1;
    window1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/ScenePackage/FXMLWindow1.fxml"));

    //Scene newSceneWindow1 = new Scene(window1);

    Stage mainStage;
    //mainStage = (Stage)  ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    mainStage = MainApplication.parentWindow;
    mainStage.getScene().setRoot(newSceneWindow1); //we dont need to change whole sceene, only set new root.
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but [you can make it better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) by including a summary or relevant portions of the video you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the link you included breaks in the future.

Comment: Now it should be clear. However I cant load a Layout when is different than AnchorPane. Application throws exception....

Comment: Making the `parentWindow` `public` and `static` is a pretty bad idea. Note that the original solution didn't assume the window was defined by the `MainApplication` class (let alone being the primary stage from it); it has no reference to that class at all. So your solution only works in that one specific case; using the original version is far more versatile.

Comment: @James_D You mean its better to do `someNode.getScene().getWindow();` ?

Comment: Yes. There is less coupling. Note that if you're just changing the root of the scene you don't need the window at all (just do `someNode.getScene().setRoot(...);`)

Comment: ahhh, Yes. I overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I recommend you to use [custom component](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm) instead. First create a custom component for your content:

```
class Content2 extends AnchorPane {
    Content() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("vista2.fxml");
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    }
}
```

Replace the `AnchorPane` markup in the root of your `vista2.fxml` file with `fx:root`:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    ...
</fx:root>
```

Then, you can do this simply by using custom event binding and arrow function. Add event handler property to your `Content` class:

```
private final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> propertyOnPreviousButtonClick = new SimpleObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>();

@FXML
private void onPreviousButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
    propertyOnPreviousButtonClick.get().handle(event)
}

public void setOnPreviousButtonClick(EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler) {
    propertyOnPreviousButtonClick.set(handler);
}
```

Finally, bind your custom event handler in your java code or fxml:

```
@FXML
onNextButtonClick() {
    Content2 content2 = new Content2();
    content2.setOnPreviousButtonClick((event) -> {
        Content1 content1 = new Content1();

        layout.getChildren().clear();
        layout.getChildren().add(content1);
    });

    layout.getChildren().clear();
    layout.getChildren().add(content2);    
}
```

If you don't want to add content dynamically, just `setVisible()` to `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

Others may have a better solution, but my solution has been to have a simple container like VBox in the outer fxml, then load the new content and add it as a child of the container.  If you're only loading one or two forms, this might be the way go to go.  However, for a more complete framework, I found this blog post helpful: https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1 She has source code for her framework which includes fancy transitions.  Although it's meant to manage top level scenes, I found it easy to adapt for managing inner content regions too.

Answer (score 0):

My example of the [mask](https://github.com/vas7n/VAnavigation).

Using:

```
Main.getNavigation().load(View2.URL_FXML).Show();
Main.getNavigation().GoBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got stuck up in this too
Tried out most of the answers, wasn't what I wanted so I just used the ideals given to do this:

```
public class Main extends Application {
public static Stage homeStage;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    homeStage = primaryStage;
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainView.fxml"));
    root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("stylesheet/custom.css").toExternalForm());
    homeStage.setTitle("Classification of Living Organisms");
    homeStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 500));
    homeStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

this is my main class. Main.java with the landing window/page mainView.fxml.
Used a little of @Tomasz idea, although confused me a lil before I did this in my mainController.java class:

```
public void gotoSubMenu(Event event) {
    Parent window1;
    try {
        window1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("src/displayView.fxml"));
        Stage window1Stage;
        Scene window1Scene = new Scene(window1, 600, 500);
        window1Stage = Main.homeStage;
        window1Stage.setScene(window1Scene);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

created a new Parent window called 'window1' that loaded the second fxml file called 'displayView.fxml' in the src directory.
created an object of the main view stage and set the scene to the newly created scene whose root is window1.
Hope this helps the ones coming into #JavaFX now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to make the button call the new fxml file, this worked for me.

```
@FXML
private void mainBClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stage stage;
    Parent root;
    stage=(Stage) ((Button)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the same scene container but changing the view inside the scene container...

Say the scene container you want to pass a new view and controller into is a GridPane layout named sceneContainer.

Establish a FXMLLoader object of the new view.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Notifications.fxml"));
```

Create a matching container and loading the contents of the new view into it.

```
GridPane yourNewView = fxmlLoader.load();
```

set the new view to the sceneContainer. (setAll clears all children first)

```
sceneContainer.getChildren().setAll(yourNewView);
```

Get the controller object for the new view and call your method that starts the class logic

```
Notifications notifications = fxmlLoader.getController();
notifications.passUserName(userName);
```

A full example would look like this :

```
@FXML
public void setNotificationsViewToScene() {

    try {
         FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Notifications.fxml"));
         GridPane yourNewView = fxmlLoader.load();
         sceneContainer.getChildren().setAll(yourNewView);

         Notifications notifications = fxmlLoader.getController();
         notifications.passUserName(userName);

    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, >8 years old with lots of complicated answers and no mention of the >10 year old solution.

There is a dedicated **fx:include** element for nesting FXML files. It's not in the SceneBuilder library, so you need to write it manually. SceneBuilder can load and display nested FXML just fine though.

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="content">
    <children>
        <fx:include fx:id="nestedVista" source="vista2.fxml" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

You can reference the nested Pane and controller using the **fx:id** and **fx:id+"Controller"**

```
@FXML
Pane nestedVista;

@FXML
VistaController nestedVistaController;
```

Documentation link: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers