# Java SceneBuilder design single panel

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

I've started a new JavaFX 2 project and I've built the main Stage with SceneBuilder. How can I design a new, separate Pane (i.e. a new FXML file with its own controller class) and add it to the main scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Static Inclusion*

`fx:include` can be placed in the parent FXML file to statically include a child FXML with it's own Controller.

For example (from the [Oracle FXML Introduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements)), given the following markup:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <fx:include source="my_button.fxml"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

If my_button.fxml contains the following:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<Button text="My Button"/>
```

the resulting scene graph would contain a VBox as a root object with a single Button as a child node.

*Dynamic Loading*

[Loading new fxml in the same scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619394/loading-new-fxml-in-the-same-scene) describes how to load the new FXML files dynamically into a replaceable child Pane.