# Java: Upgrading to a single window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I have been coding Java for a few months now, and I have been using `JOptionPane` to display text and variables in my games. I want to upgrade to a single window like a normal game, but I want to only focus on simple buttons and text on the screen. I have tried learning `JFrame` and `ActionListsner`, but I failed to completley figure it out. `JFrame` really confused me.

**My question is this**: Is there an easier way beside `JFrame` to just have a window that I can have simple text, buttons and `TextFields` without the hassle of opening a bunch of windows with `JOptionPane`, making crap loads of `ActionListener`s with `JFrame` or having to get into GUI? If not, where can I find help on how to make games with `JFrame`?

Comment: Re your deleted question, there is http://rpg.stackexchange.com/ and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using a `JFrame`. Trust me, they aren't that hard to use. Using a `JFrame`, you could create multiple *panels* and switch between them using `CardLayout`.

Since you said you aren't sure about how `JFrame` works, I gave *a short introduction to them at the end of this post*. But first, lets first talk about how to solve your problem.

---

**Switching Panels via CardLayout**

When you want to switch whats being viewed in the window completely, you're gonna want an entirely different panel for that specific purpose (for example, one for Main Menu, and one for the game). `CardLayout` was created for this.

You specify a "deck" panel. This panel will hold all the other panels you wanna switch between (cards):

```
CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
JPanel deck = new JPanel();
deck.setLayout(layout);
```

You'll need to maintain a reference to the layout (via a variable) so you can switch between panels.

Now that we have a "deck" panel, we need to add some cards. We do this by creating more JPanels, and specifying a name when we add it to the frame (constraints):

```
JPanel firstCard = new JPanel();
JPanel secondCard = new JPanel();
deck.add(firstCard, "first");
deck.add(secondCard, "second");
```

The first card added to the deck will always be the first one to show.

Once you have all your cards added, you can switch between them by calling `layout.show(deck, "second");`. This is how you use `CardLayout` to manage multiple panels within your container.

---

**Creating listeners**

There's no easier way to manage it. It only gets harder from there (bindings - I highly suggest you [look into them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)). For listeners, there are 2 steps:

1. Create the listener
2. Add it to the component

Could be 1 if you created the listener "on the fly" using a lambda:

```
JButton button = new JButton();

//Java 8+
button.addActionListener(event -> {
    //whenever you click the button, code in here triggers
});
```

For those who don't use Java 8, you will need to use an *anonymous class*:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //whenever you click the button, code in here triggers
    }
});
```

Only some components support `ActionListener`. Anything that extends `AbstractButton`, like `JMenuItem`, `JButton`, `JRadioButton`, and more will support `ActionListener`s. `JTextField` also supports it, even though it's not an `AbstractButton`. Every component supports `KeyListener`, though, which can also be used to listen for input events from the user.

If you have any questions about this, let me know and I'll be glad to answer them.

---

**Using Swing Components**

**JFrame**

You initialize a `JFrame`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

You then want to set the `defaultCloseOperation`, to determine what happens when the window closes:
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

There are different options, but `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` will terminate your program after closing the window. **If you do not set the `defaultCloseOperation`, then your window will close, but your program will still be running. BIG NO NO**. If you don't want the entire program to exit when you close the frame, use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

After you have the close operation, you might be tempted to set the size. *This is bad practice*. Your frame should size depending on what's inside of it. To do this, you add your components to your frame, then call `pack()`:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
frame.add(button);
//add other components
frame.pack();
```

This will ensure your frame sizes to fit what's inside of it. You should always design GUI from the inside out, to ensure you always have enough room for what you need.

**Containers**

`JFrame` is a `Container`. Containers are just components that hold other components. All containers should have a `LayoutManager` to manage how components are laid out and, if needed, sized. `JFrame` isn't the only container though. `JPanel` is actually a container that's meant to be added to another container (or window). You can add things to a `JPanel`, then add that panel to another container. This is how you keep things neatly organized. Containers are pretty straight forward, so there's not much to talk about.

**Content Pane**

When you create a `JFrame`, it comes along with something called the `contentPane`. It is a `JPanel` nested within the JFrame. When you do `frame.add(button)`, you'll notice that `add` actually refers to the contentPane:

```
//in Container class
public Component add(Component comp) {
    addImpl(comp, null, -1); //where it's added
    return comp;
}

//In JFrame class (overriding)
protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
    if(isRootPaneCheckingEnabled()) {
        getContentPane().add(comp, constraints, index); //adds to content pane instead
    } else {
        super.addImpl(comp, constraints, index); //if root panes were not supported, which they currently are
    }
}
```

You too can grab the contentPane from the frame using

```
Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
```

The reason why the contentPane is in `Container` form is to ensure a strong API (if JPanels were no longer going to be used for this, we wouldn't need to worry about changing the method type of getContentPane). Although, since it IS a JPanel, you can cast it back to it's original form:

```
JPanel pane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
```

Although it's usually not needed. Using it as a `Container` tends to work just fine.

**Layouts**

`JFrame`, by default, uses `BorderLayout`, but you can change this by calling the `setLayout` method of the container:

```
FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
frame.setLayout(layout);
```

Before jumping into layouts, I want to mention that `JPanel`s use `FlowLayout` as default, **except for the frame's default contentPane**, which you can also change by doing `frame.setContentPane(...)`. The contentPane uses `BorderLayout` as default.

Now, lets talk about a couple, starting with the `JFrame` default: [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

Some layouts require what are called *constraints*, which tell the layout how to handle that specific component that's being added. You specify these constraints when you add the component to the container:

```
frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

`BorderLayout` is pretty simple. You have 5 options: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, or CENTER. (there are other values such as PAGE_START, which are interchangeable. It's best to just use the easier form)

All constraints for `BorderLayout` are static field variables that you call similar to how I did. `BorderLayout` is actually an easy layout to use, seeing how there's not much to it. Even though it's simplicity limits what you can do (you can only put it in a certain position like NORTH), you'd usually combine layouts to get the result you want. This layout can be very powerful when combined with other layouts.

[`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) is pretty straight forward, as well as other layouts out there. One of the less straight-forward ones would be [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), which can be a really flexible layout. It can also be pretty complex, though, as the documentation even states.

When using `GridBagLayout`, you need to create a constraints object: [`GridBagConstraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html). To work with `GridBagLayout`, you set the constraints using the constraints object, then add both the component and the constraints to the container:

```
 frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
 GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

 JButton button = new JButton("yoyoyo");
 frame.add(button, gbc);
```

Even if we don't adjust the constraints, we MUST still specify it when adding a component to the container.

Lets say we had 4 buttons, and we wanted to put them side by side. You would adjust the constraint's `gridx` and `gridy` values:

```
JButton button = new JButton("1");
JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
JButton button4 = new JButton("4");

frame.add(button, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1; //or gridx += 1, or gridx = 1. gridx starts at 0
frame.add(button2, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 0; //must reset the value back to normal
gbc.gridy = 1;
frame.add(button3, gbc);

gbc.gridx = 1;
//since gridy already == 1, no need to change it
frame.add(button4, gbc);
```

We can use the same constraints object, as long as we reset values when needed.

`GridBagLayout` starts centered, and works from the center out, unless you specify otherwise. You cannot skip grid spaces either. Also, as you'll notice, all your buttons will be touching. If you wanted a little space between each component, you can set the `insets` of the constraints:

```
int top = 5, left = 5, bottom = 1, right = 1; 
gbc.insets.set(top, left, bottom, right);
```

There is a LOT more to this layout, and sadly I just don't feel this is the best place to give the explanation to it all, seeing how it's already documented (I even added the link).

There are many other layouts out there. Get familiar with as many as you possibly can, then find the ones that'll help suit your needs. Positioning should ALWAYS rely on the `LayoutManager` that's being used. As for sizing, that kinda depends on the layout you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is what you're looking for. With it, the programmer can choose which JPanels should be visible in the JFrame. Upon user interaction you can switch the contents of the JFrame without new JFrames or JOptionPanes popping up.

Is there an easier way than using Swing for simple games? Swing has a learning curve, but with the right resources and practice you can learn to build simple GUI applications pretty quickly.

Comment: nonono, I don't want the player to have to switch between different tabs manually, I want it to be like an average game where you click a button and it takes you to a different menu. I also don't want them to be ABLE to switch to menus in a game through tabs

Comment: The CardLayout isn't a tabbed layout. You change switch the visible JPanels in the JFrame based on user interaction.

Comment: @pebble225 "You" meaning the programmer, not the user. Practically any GUI application framework will involve something like ActionListeners. If you're having trouble with them you just need more practice :)

Comment: @pebble225 unfortunately, no. I can't suggest any more than googling for articles or finding a book on Swing which covers it.

Comment: Oracle have a [CardLayout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  Here is a [similar example for JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619394/loading-new-fxml-in-the-same-scene) in case you switch to that UI framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using JavaFX. It's a very nice fairly easy to use GUI system with nice looking and customizable controls. JavaFX events (basically ActionListeners) are pretty straightforward as well.

This should get you started: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm#JFXST804

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question. Question: "*How do I upgrade to a single window?*", Your answer: "*I recommend using JavaFX*". JavaFX allows multiple windows aswell.

Comment: The OP asked for an easier way than the 'JFrame' solution, so i recommended JavaFX, which is in my opinion easier. I would also like to point out that JavaFX is geared towards a single window, more so than Swing anyways.

Comment: You don't show him *how* to achieve this in FX. Those reading this in the future will still not understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, i will agree with that. I answered this question before I was very familiar with the site. If I find the time, I will expand this question to get a reader started with the basics of JavaFX.