# Setting center of borderpane form another controller class

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I have Borderpane as homePane (its fxml file is home.fxml). At first in center of homePane i have a HBox which contains a button   called delivery. When the user clicks this button, the center of homePane switchs to display the list of customers.
It works !

The code of homeController :

```
public class HomeController {

@FXML
private BorderPane homePane; 

@FXML
public void deliveryBtnClicked (){
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fragments/customers.fxml"));
    homePane.getChildren().remove(homePane.getCenter());
    try {
        Pane pane = loader.load();
        homePane.setCenter(pane);

    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public BorderPane getHomePane() {
    return homePane;
}
}
```

The new Pane contains the table of customers and a button called order. It has own Controller :

```
public class CustomerController {
    
    @FXML
    public void loadOrderView() throws IOException {
        Customer customer = customerTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/home.fxml"));
        loader.load();

        HomeController homeController =  loader.getController();
        BorderPane homePane = homeController.getHomePane();


        homePane.getChildren().remove(homePane.getCenter());
        System.out.println(homePane.getCenter());
        FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fragments/order.fxml"));
        Pane orderView = loader1.load();
        homePane.setCenter(orderView);
        System.out.println(homePane.getCenter());
     }
}
```

When user clicks the button order, the order-view have to be loaded in the center of homePane.
the print command shows that the homePane center after removed is null and then after loaded gets new view.

```
null
AnchorPane@755b1503
```

But in running Programm its doen't show the order view. I have set onAction of button order to loadOrderView. This is definitive not the problem.

Comment: You’re loading `home.fxml` a second time, creating a second border pane (and a second instance of `HomeController`). That second border pane is not part of the scene, so you won’t see anything when you change its content.

Comment: You either need to pass the `BorderPane` or the instance of the `BorderPane` or the *current* instance of `HomeController` to the `CustomerController` (both bad options imo) or use a model or view-model which encapsulates the current view state and share it with both controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your anwer. I don't know how can i use a model or view-model. Can you please show a example ?

Comment: @jewelsea yes, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate the scene graph as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065648/2189127), and this is a perfectly good solution for a small application.

For larger applications, where you might need more flexibility in terms of the ability to change, e.g., how the layout is managed, consider using a MVC/MVVM type of approach. Start with a model class that maintains the current view state:

```
public class ViewModel {

    public enum View {
        CUSTOMER(ViewModel.class.getResource("/fragments/customer.fxml")),
        ORDER(ViewModel.class.getResource("/fragments/order.fxml"));

        private final URL resource ;

        private View(URL resource) {
            this.resource = resource ;
        }

        public URL getResource() {
            return resource ;
        }
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<View> currentView = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public ObjectProperty<View> currentViewProperty() {
        return currentView ;
    }

    public final View getCurrentView() {
        return currentViewProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setCurrentView(View currentView) {
        currentViewProperty().set(currentView);
    }
}
```

Make your controllers implement an interface that allows them to have a reference to a `ViewModel`:

```
public interface ViewModelObserver {
    public void setViewModel(ViewModel model);
}
```

Your `HomeController`, assuming it is loaded once and the home page is always shown, can create a single instance of the `ViewModel`, observe it, update the border pane, and pass the instance to other controllers when they are loaded:

```
public class HomeController  {

    private final ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();

    @FXML
    private BorderPane homePane; 
    
    @FMXL
    public void initialize() {
        viewModel.currentViewProperty().addListener((obs, oldView, newView) -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(newView.getResource());
                Parent root = loader.load();
                Object controller = loader.getController();
                if (controller instanceof ViewModelObserver) {
                    ((ViewModelObserver)controller).setViewModel(viewModel);
                }
                homePane.setCenter(root);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void deliveryBtnClicked (){
        viewModel.setCurrentView(ViewModel.View.CUSTOMER);
    }


}
```

Then make the controllers for the FXML "fragments" implement `ViewModelObserver`. They can simply update the current view, and the home controller will load and display it:

```
public class CustomerController implements ViewModelObserver {

    private ViewModel viewModel ;

    @Override
    public void setViewModel(ViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel ;
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void loadOrderView() throws IOException {
        viewModel.setCurrentView(ViewModel.View.ORDER);
     }
}
```

You may need to include other properties in your view model, e.g. to give access to the `Customer` instance etc.

Answer (score 2):

As James has pointed out, you should not load the home fxml again.

Instead:

1. Define the orderButton in your controller and in your fxml (via a `fx:id` and `@FXML` injection).
2. Use the scene graph to find the home pane so that you can replace its center.

```
public class CustomerController {
    
    @FXML Button orderButton
    
    @FXML
    public void loadOrderView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fragments/order.fxml"));
        Pane orderView = loader.load();
        BorderPane homePane = (BorderPane) orderButton.getScene().getRoot();
        homePane.setCenter(orderView);
     }
}
```

An alternate method in a small framework is defined in the answer to:

- [Loading new fxml in the same scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619394/loading-new-fxml-in-the-same-scene)