# switch a screen when clicking on an node of a tree

Tags: javafx, treeview, fxml

I am trying to load a new FXML when clicking on item of a treeview.

Well, There is a part of MainApp, where FXML are loaded.
Here I have implemented a root view in which other views will be loaded.

I try to load  *clientView.fxml* when someone clicks on the node "**voir mes clients**" on treeview. The view will be wrapped in the view loaded by *menuView.fxml* in function *mainMenuView*

In class *TreeLoadingEventHandler*, function *handle* load the treeview implemented in the controller and finally the treeview is loaded in  the function *mainMenuView*.

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootView;
    private static AnchorPane menuView;

    public MainApp()
    {}

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage=primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("MaK@mpta");

        launchRootLayout();
        mainMenuView();
        }   

    public void launchRootLayout()
    {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/rootView.fxml"));
            rootView = (BorderPane)loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootView);
            //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void mainMenuView()
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/menuView.fxml"));
            menuView=(AnchorPane)loader.load();
            rootView.setCenter(menuView);
            MenuViewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
            //controller.loadItems();
            TreeLoadingEventHandler Tree=new TreeLoadingEventHandler(controller);
            Tree.handle(null);   

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showClient()
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/clientView.fxml"));
            AnchorPane clientView=(AnchorPane)loader.load();
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(clientView, 220.0);
            menuView.getChildren().add(clientView);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

     private class TreeLoadingEventHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
            private MenuViewController controller;

            TreeLoadingEventHandler(MenuViewController controller) {
              this.controller = controller;
            }    
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
              controller.loadItems();
            }
          }

}
```

Here is the java class which implements the controller
 function *setMainApp* retrieves the reference of controller from which I can call the function *showClient* of the *MainApp*.
I have implemented a cell factory *setfactoryCell* to invoke  the loading of clientView.fxml when someone clicks on item "voir mes clients".

```
public class MenuViewController {

    @FXML
    TreeView <String> treeview;

    // Reference to the main application.
    private MainApp mainApp;

   // public MenuViewController()

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        loadItems();
    }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void loadItems()
    {
          TreeItem<String>root=new TreeItem<>("Root");

          TreeItem<String> clients=new TreeItem<>("Clients");
          TreeItem<String> addClient=new TreeItem<>("Ajouter Client");
          TreeItem<String> seeClient=new TreeItem<>("Voir mes clients");

          TreeItem<String> articles=new TreeItem<>("Articles");
          TreeItem<String> devis=new TreeItem<>("Devis");

          root.getChildren().addAll(clients,articles,devis);
          clients.getChildren().addAll(addClient,seeClient);

          root.setExpanded(true);
          treeview.setRoot(root);
          treeview.setShowRoot(false);  
          setfactoryCell();
    }

    private void  setfactoryCell()
    {
        treeview.setCellFactory(tree -> {
            TreeCell<String> cell = new TreeCell<String>() {
             @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
                    if (empty) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(item);
                    }
                }
            };
            cell.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
                    TreeItem<String> treeItem = cell.getTreeItem();
                    // do whatever you need with the treeItem...
                    if (treeItem.getValue().equals("Voir mes clients"))
                    {
                        selectViewClient();
                    }
                }
            });
            return cell ;
        });
    }
      /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */

      public void selectViewClient()
      {
          mainApp.showClient();
      }

      public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
      this.mainApp = mainApp;
      }
}
```

This thing doesn't work.
Even The treeview which worked before , doesn't work anymore.
Could I have a help on this please ? 
How to do this working when I click on the item "voir mes clients" ?
Sorry for posting so much code but I don't see here how to be more short.

Thank you

Comment: Possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176701/switch-between-panes-in-javafx

Comment: Hi Dmytro, I don't see how it can help me